# Migrating from django-registration to django-allauth

Tags: django-registration, django-allauth

I have an existing Django system which uses django-registration.

I'd like to move away from django-registration, which is no longer actively maintained.

django-allauth looks a good candidate for a replacement.

Has anyone managed to migrate from django-registration to django-allauth?

Any gotchas to look out for?

Rachel

Comment: Answering my own question.... it turned out to be relatively easy to switch the accounts-only signups (will try the social-accounts later) http://blog.willmer.org/2014/04/migrating-django-registration-django-allauth/